# How to write this MySQL subquery to select rows that have a common value and one known value

Tags: php, mysql, subquery

If I have a table with two rows that share a common value. I know the 'known_value' and I'm trying to fetch the (unknown) one.  The setup looks like this:

```
+-----------+------------+----------------+
|  post_id  |  meta_key  |  meta_value    |
+-----------+------------+----------------+
|    20     |  'key_1'   |   (unknown)    |
+-----------+------------+----------------+
|    20     |  'key_2'   | 'known_value'  |
+-----------+------------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to write a single subquery that will accomplish this, but it doesn't work:

```
$sql = "SELECT `meta_value` FROM `my_table` WHERE `meta_key` = 'key_1' AND `post_id` = (SELECT `post_id` FROM `my_table` WHERE `meta_key` = 'key_2' AND `meta_value` = %s)";
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, array( 'known_value' ) );
$result = $wpdb->get_var($sql);
```

I can get it to work if I write it in two steps, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT `post_id` FROM `my_table` WHERE `meta_key` = 'key_2' AND `meta_value` = %s";
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, array( 'known_value ) );
$post_id = $wpdb->get_var($sql);

// this gets the post_id of 20

$sql = "SELECT `meta_value` FROM `my_table` WHERE `meta_key` = 'key_1' AND `post_id` = %d";
$sql = $wpdb->prepare( $sql, array( $post_id) );
$result = $wpdb->get_var($sql);

// this gets the (unknown) value
```

How do I write it in a single step with a subquery?  Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your query works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e76cba/1

Comment: Could there be more than one row with `meta_key = key_2` and `meta_value = known_value`? If the subquery can return more than one `post_id` you need to use `IN` rather than `=`.

Comment: I think that was the problem. I changed = to IN and it seems to be working as expected now.  Thank you!